# C++, Ncurses - trouble understanding how menu windows work

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, ncurses, roguelike

I have two version of my program. One that uses ncurses and another that doesn't. The one which doe not use ncurses works well enough, nothing is wrong with it. I want to upgrade my program so I decided that I will use ncurses for that. The problem is I don't understand how the window system works. There is no decent documentations and the tutorials aren't very helpful. What I am asking is for general help regarding windows in ncurses as well as an example of such the feature working using my code.

What I tried:

```
//g++ main.cpp -lncurses -W -Wall -Wpedandtic -std=c++23; ./a.out
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "ncurses.h"

void start() {
  initscr();
  noecho();
  std::cout << "Hello, word!" << '\n';
  getch();
}

int main() {
  initscr();
  noecho();
  cbreak();

  int yMax;
  int xMax;
  getmaxyx(stdscr, yMax, xMax);

  std::string line;
  std::ifstream file("resources/graphics/logo.txt");
  if(file.is_open()) {
    while(getline(file, line)) {
      std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
  } else {
    std::cout << "logo.txt could not be found!" << '\n';
  }
  
  WINDOW * menuwin = newwin(6, xMax / 2, 10, xMax / 4);
  keypad(menuwin, true);
  box(menuwin, 0, 0);
  refresh();
  wrefresh(menuwin);

  std::string choices[4] = {"Start", "Continue", "Settings", "Controls"};
  int choice;
  int highlight = 0;
  while(1) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
      if(i == highlight) {
    wattron(menuwin, A_REVERSE);
      }
      mvwprintw(menuwin, i + 1, 1, choices[i].c_str());
      wattroff(menuwin, A_REVERSE);
    }
    choice = wgetch(menuwin);
    switch(choice) {
    case KEY_UP:
      highlight--;
      if(highlight == -1) {
    highlight = 0;
      }
      break;
    case KEY_DOWN:
      highlight++;
      if(highlight == 4) {
    highlight = 3 ;
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
    //keycode 10 = enter;
    if(choice == 10) {
      break;
    }
  }
  if(choices[highlight].c_str() == 0 | 1 | 2 | 3) {
    start();
  }
  //printw("%s", choices[highlight].c_str());
  getch();
  endwin();
}
```

What I expected(graphical representation):

```
        ####
       #     #   ####   #####   #    #  #   ####   #    #  #  #####   ######
       #        #    #  #    #  ##   #  #  #       #    #  #  #    #  #
       #  ####  #    #  #    #  # #  #  #   ####   ######  #  #    #  #####
       #     #  #    #  #####   #  # #  #       #  #    #  #  #####   #
       #     #  #    #  #   #   #   ##  #  #    #  #    #  #  #   #   #
        #####    ####   #    #  #    #  #   ####   #    #  #  #    #  ######
                                                               #    
       #          ##    #####   #   #  #####   #  #    #    #    #    #
       #         #  #   #    #  #  #   #    #  #  ##   #    #    #    #
       #        #    #  #####    ##    #    #  #  # #  #    #    ######
       #        ######  #    #   #     #####   #  #  # #    #    #    #
       #        #    #  #    #  #      #   #   #  #   ##    #    #    #
       #######  #    #  #####  #       #    #  #  #    #  #####  #    #
                  #             #              #             #
                                                #
                                  Start
                                  Continue
                                  Settings
                                  Controls
```

What I got(graphical representation):

```
Start
Continue
Settings
Controls[]Hello, world!
```

The [] represents a graphical glitch, btw.

I have a main2.cpp where I tried adding multiple windows but what happens is they load independently of each others. So, windows1 loads, waits for input, and closes. Then window2 opens. I want both of them to be open or preferable for both of the functions to be in the same windows.

Comment: Fixed the graphical glitch with: curs_set(0);

Answer (score 0):

In ncurses, each window is a separate entity and they don't know about each other. When you refresh a window, it gets drawn on the virtual screen. The actual screen doesn't get updated until you call `refresh()` or `doupdate()`.

In your code, you're using `std::cout` to print the logo and the "Hello, world!" message. However, `std::cout` doesn't work well with ncurses because ncurses uses its own buffering system. Instead, you should use ncurses functions like `printw()`, `mvprintw()`, `wprintw()`, or `mvwprintw()` to print to the screen or a window.

For your issue with multiple windows, you need to create and refresh all your windows first, then call `doupdate()` to update the actual screen. This way, all your windows will appear at the same time.

```cpp
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
    initscr();
    noecho();
    cbreak();

    int yMax, xMax;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, yMax, xMax);

    WINDOW *win1 = newwin(yMax / 2, xMax / 2, 0, 0);
    box(win1, 0, 0);
    mvwprintw(win1, 1, 1, "This is window 1");
    wrefresh(win1);

    WINDOW *win2 = newwin(yMax / 2, xMax / 2, yMax / 2, xMax / 2);
    box(win2, 0, 0);
    mvwprintw(win2, 1, 1, "This is window 2");
    wrefresh(win2);

    doupdate();

    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My program relies on fstream and cout. How can I implement fstream with ncurses?